# LibreOffice: Advanced Filter with Named Ranges

Tags: filter, libreoffice-calc, named-ranges

I have a (rather big) table which I want to filter. Since the filter is complicated I am using "advanced filter". This works fine if I input the cell-range where the advanced filter is located (e.g. `$Sheet1.$F$18:$F$21`) in the Advanced Filter Filter-Criteria dialog.

Now, since I want to have multiple advanced filters and since selecting them every time is quite cumbersome I thought of using **named ranges**. Then I could simply imput `fa`, `fb`, `fc` for my different filter criterias. But the Advanced Filter dialog does not accept this. I get an `invalid sheet reference` error.

How can I use named ranges together with advanced filters? Or is there another easy way to have pre-defined filters which can easily be activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, while setting the named range, set [x] Filter in Range Options:

[image]

Then you can select that named range as filter while setting advanced filter:

[image]

As you see, you will select the named range from the leftmost dropdown box.

Comment: Thank you. I saw the "Filter" checkbox, but I did not realize I have to select it from the dropdown menu of the advanced filter. This works great